# How to solve $2^{(x+1)^2}$ modulo $m$ (not prime) where $(x+1)^2$ overflows?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As stated in the question, I am trying to write a generic solver for $2^{(x+1)^2}$ modulo $m$ where $m$ is not prime. Normally you can just do exponentiated squaring with modulus to get the answer, but the problem I have is that $(x+1)^2$ is too large to store in a standard datatype like unsigned long long in C++. Doing $2^{(x+1)^2~mod~m}~mod ~m$ is also wrong.

Is there any way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to solve for $x$, or compute that power of $2$ given $x$?

If the latter, and assuming $m$ is odd, you can use Euler's theorem: $2^a \equiv 2^{a\ \bmod\ \phi(m)} \pmod m$. Of course, here $m$ must be small enough to factor efficiently, or you must have some special knowledge of $\phi(m)$.

In the worst case, you can always rewrite $2^{(x+1)^2} = (2^{x+1})^{x+1}$, where $x+1$ presumably fits inside an integer, and so each exponentiation can be done using repeated squaring.

Comment: Computing 2 to (x+1)^2, result modulo m. x is given